# How to make php hidden texts

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

Im making new website for me, and I want to make 404 that will work like that:
I will enter bad url and it will redict me to default page
And in the default page will apear hiden php 404 text.
Please help me someone, I tried to search and tried much of ways but nothing worked.

Comment: Which webserver are you using, its the web server that handles generating 404 responses.

Comment: Apache2 on Debian.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your .htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

where 404.php is the file name and placed at root. You can put full path over here.

Comment: I don't think you even need the `RewriteEngine On` part.

Comment: @sdexp you don't `ErrorDocument` is a built in command in apache

Comment: I didnt mean it as this, I already have htaccess that sends me to index.php but there I want when i sends there appear a 404 text. Like iv seen localhost?=404, it short, I want it in one document

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?id=404
```

At index page... just check for the error code in the URL and display a hidden message through PHP.